# Drunk Mandelbrot implementation

Tags: c++, fractals, allegro, allegro5, mandelbrot

I wrote a program that is supposed to draw the Mandelbrot fractal. Unfortunately, it seems to be drunk. Here is the output:

[image: Failed Mandelbrot]

The relevant function:

```
void drawMandelbrot(float x, float y, float width, float height, float delta) {
    for (float currentX = -2; currentX < 2; currentX += delta) {
        for (float currentY = -2; currentY < 2; currentY += delta) {
            Complex z(0, 0);
            Complex c(currentX, currentY);
            int iterations = 0;

            do {
                z = z * z + c;
                ++iterations;
            }
            while (z.getAbsoluteValue() <= 2 && iterations < MANDELBROT_ITERATION_LIMIT);

            ALLEGRO_COLOR pixelColor;
            float pixelX = (currentX + 2) / 4 * width;
            float pixelY = (currentY + 2) / 4 * width;

            if (z.getAbsoluteValue() <= 2) {
                pixelColor = blackColor;
                // Commented because you might not want this much junk in your terminal
                //std::cout << "Stayed small! " << z.toString() << std::endl;
            } else {
                pixelColor = al_color_hsv(iterations / MANDELBROT_ITERATION_LIMIT, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                // idem
                //std::cout << "Blew up! " << z.toString() << std::endl;
            }
            al_draw_pixel(pixelX, pixelY, pixelColor);
        }
    }
}
```

I believe the `Complex::operator...` methods are correct, I suspect a logic error in the above function. When checking the output of the above (commented) std::cout statements, the absolute values of the complex numbers in the output is indeed less than 2, yet the image doesn't look like the plotted mandelbrot set.

Where is the wrong condition?

---

An mcve is included in the edit history.

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: What are we supposed to be doing?  Compiling, executing and debugging your code?

Comment: @Arkapravo There must be some logic error in `drawMandelbrot()`. All the picture I saw of the Mandelbrot set I saw online look a lot more symmetrical. Will edit.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I admit it is a lot of code, but last time I encountered a logic problem in an isolated function, the feedback I got was "post an mcve", although the question was correctly answered before I could edit it into the question. This time, I thought to include it up front, but due to the complex number maths the "minimum" is still a lot. I was hoping somebody would look at `drawMandelbrot()` and spot an off-by-one mistake or similar.

Comment: I would write some unit tests to verify your assertion that the Complex class is correct.

Comment: Why did you write your own Complex class instead of std::complex?

Comment: Increase your `MANDELBROT_ITERATION_LIMIT` and cast at least one operand to float before doing the division `iterations / MANDELBROT_ITERATION_LIMIT`.

Comment: @Puppy 1) I didn't know until the std::complex class until now, 2) as an exercise.

Comment: You removed the code with the error in it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation of the complex modulus is incorrect.

```
float Complex::getAbsoluteValue() const {
    return sqrt(real * real + imaginary + imaginary);
}
```

You've since removed this section of your post, but it should say

```
float Complex::getAbsoluteValue() const {
    return sqrt(real * real + imaginary * imaginary);
}
```